# OpenGL es 2.0 blend issue

Tags: opengl-es

Now I learning OpenGL ES 2.0 with iOS and try to develop the drawing functions in iPhone.

I have success to draw a line art image and live drawing with finger, thanks to GLPaint.

Live drawing can covered the line art image, but I want the line art drawing without cover the black line.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrhE1.png) This is now I've done with drawing.

Is there any good blend method to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally done with this issue.

It's simple to use glBlendFunc:

glEnable(GL_BLEND);

glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

The point is

1. First parameter is destination color (background color), second is source color.
2. For default, glBlendEquation is set to GL_FUNC_ADD; if you want to do something different, please remember to change with different case.

   In this issue, we don't need to change it, cause we need blend background color with brush color, and black color always cover any color when add two of them.
3. Make sure set "glEnable(GL_BLEND)" after draw background image.

   My mistake is, setting glEnable(GL_BLEND) with compile brush shader, and draw after set all shaders.